# What is the diffrence between Non-Consecutive GoTo Repetition Operator and Repetition Non-Consecutive in system verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification, system-verilog-assertions, vlsi

I'm currently reading Ashok Mehta's system Verilog assertion textbook. Now I have encountered a doubt. I couldn't understand what is the difference between -> and = operator. I.e,  Non-Consecutive GoTo Repetition Operator and Repetition Non-Consecutive. Some please explain what is the difference. The timing things in the textbook will be similar even if we used = instead of ->. Please explain me.

[image: Here this is the snapshot for Ashok Mehta's book]

Answer (score 3):

The difference comes into play is when a sequence follows these repetition operators.

```
b[=2] ##1 c
```

is equivalent to

```
b[->2] ##1 !b[*0:$] ##1 c
```

There are other ramifications when using these operators discussed [here](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/difference-between-goto-and-non-consecutive-repetition-assertion)